# Print a web page from a webview

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I made an app that is just a webview showing a website, at a certain point in my website I have a button that prints a div via javascript, as it is it doesn't work, how can I make it possible?

my js code:

```
     function printDiv(divName) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

    window.print();

    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

Comment: have you enabled javascript for WebView?

Comment: yes I did, all other scripts works correctly

Comment: can you show us the code of print button

Comment: updated with the js code